# What happens when a character that is currently possessed by a ghost receives a communication via the Sending spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, possession, spirits

I am running a D&D 5e campaign.  I'm pretty certain my players will try to contact one character they've met previously through the *sending* spell.

That character is a ghost hunter.  It would fit very well in the campaign for that character to be possessed when the PCs try to contact him.

- Does the ghost receive/hear it?
- Does the player receive the *sending*?
- Can the player or the ghost reply to it?
- If they reply, what voice will my PC hear - the character's or the
  ghost's?

Comment: Related question on [Sending spell to a creature inhabited by an intellect devourer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157439/if-the-sending-spell-is-cast-to-communicate-with-a-character-whose-body-is-inhab)

Comment: Welcome to our stack! Great first question! Please feel free to take the [tour] and you can also visit the [help] for more about how we operate here.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [Who do you reach with Sending, when the target's soul is in another body?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198094), [Can a Sending (3rd level spell) contact a soul or just a living creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198060)

Comment: Another possible dupe, [How does the Sending spell work if you are deceived in being familiar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/166602/38834)

Comment: Reading the related questions and going through the description of the ghost's possession one more time, I believe the character will be able to receive and answer to the message, as the ghost takes control of the body, but the character does not lose its awareness. Does that make sense?

Comment: I edited the secondary question about how long someone can be possessed by a ghost out of your post, since it's a completely separate question. Feel free to ask about it in a new question (assuming it hasn't already been asked elsewhere on the site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### According to the ghost attributes in the Fifth Edition System Reference Document, the possessed character may be targeted by the *sending* spell without any interference from the ghost.

#### Does the ghost receive/hear it?

> **Possession (Recharge 6):** One Humanoid that the ghost can see... must succeed on a DC 13 Charisma saving throw or be possessed by the ghost; the ghost then disappears, and the target is Incapacitated and loses control of its body. The ghost now controls the body but *doesn't deprive the target of awareness*. *The ghost can't be targeted by any* Attack, *spell*, or other Effect, except ones that turn Undead... *[The ghost] doesn't gain access to the target's knowledge*... (SRD page 311)

No, the ghost does not receive or hear the *sending* message. The ghost's possession ability indicates it cannot access the mind of the *possession* target. The ghost also cannot be targeted by the *sending* spell, so its effects would not apply to the ghost.

#### Does the player receive the sending?

Yes, as the quote above indicates, the target of *possession* does not lose awareness. They remain a valid target for the *sending* spell.

#### Can the player or the ghost reply to it?

If the player casts the *sending* spell, they can send a message to the possessed character. The possessed character can reply. The ghost is not necessarily aware that the spell was even cast.

### If they reply, what voice will my PC hear - the character's or the ghost's?

*Sending* never specifies what voice the message is sent in.

> The creature hears the message in its mind, recognizes you as the sender if it knows you, and can answer in a like manner immediately.

The target recognizes the caster as if it knows the caster. Thus, it would be reasonable to rule that the voices heard in the characters' minds would be like the characters remember each other, not necessarily as they actually sound. For example, if two characters had not met since childhood, their voices might have changed, but the way they remember each other's voices would not have changed to how they actually sound. This is entirely up to the discretion of the DM.